# What's the proper way to access a previous page's elements using Protractor?

Tags: selenium, protractor

I have a test where I click through list of links on a page. If I open the links in new pages, I can iterate through the list using browser.switchTo().window and the original window's handle, clicking on each one.

But if I open a link in the same page (_self) and I navigate back to the original list of links using browser.navigate().back(), I get the following error when it iterates to click the next link:

```
StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

What's the proper way to access elements on a prior page once you've navigated away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you request a object from Selenium, Selenium IDs that object with a internal Unique ID. See the below command

```
>>> driver.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement 
(session="93fc2bec-c9f8-0c46-aec3-1939af00c917", 
element="5173f7fb-63ca-e447-b176-4a226d956834")>
```

As you can see the element has a unique uuid. Selenium maintains these list internally, so when you take an action like click, it fetches the element from its cached and takes action on it.

Once the page is refreshed or a new page is loaded, this cache is no longer valid. But the object you created in your language binding still is. If I try and execute some action on its

```
>>> elem.is_displayed()
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: 
Message: The element reference of [object Null] null 
stale: either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed
```

So in short there is no way to use the same object. Which means you need to alter your approach. Consider the below code

```
for elem in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a"):
    elem.click()
    driver.back()
```

Above code will fail on the second attempt of `elem.click()`. So the fix is to make sure not to re-use a collection object. Instead use a number based loop. I can write the above code in many different ways. Consider few approaches below

**Approach 1**

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
count = len(elems)
for i in range(0, count):
    elems[i].click()
    driver.back()
    elems = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
```

This is not a very great approach as I am getting a collection of objects and only using one of them. A page which would have 500+ odd links will make this code quite slow

**Approach 2**

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
count = len(elems)
for i in range(1, count + 1):
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//a)[{}]".format(i))
    driver.back()
```

This is better than approach 1 as I am getting all objects just one. Latter I am getting one and using one

**Approach 3**

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
links = []

for elem in elems:
    links.append(elem.get_attribute("href"))

for link in links:
    driver.get(link)
    # do some action
```

This approach will only work when links are href based. So it is that based on the situation I would choose or alter my approach